# Kraken Api, withdrawal issue "Invalid asset"

Tags: ruby, api, bitcoin, kraken.com

I'm trying to make a withdraw from my Kraken account to another platform, but i always get this error response:

> EFunding:Invalid asset (KrakenClient::ErrorResponse)

Using this code:

```
@kraken = KrakenClient.load

def withdraw_order_kraken
  params = {
    asset:'XBT',
    key:'Bitstamp',
    amount: 0.005
  }
  @kraken.private.withdraw(params)
end
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

I can do any others actions, public or private (even buy or sell). I tried XXBT/XBT/BTC/Bitcoin and i do have 0.005 BTC available on this account.

The error message is not in the Kraken's API docs.

Comment: I just tried with BCH as an asset and it works. I think it comes from kraken but why do they consider XBT as an invalid asset ??

Comment: try `XXBT` as asset

Answer (score -1):

`asset` need to be specified as **lowercase**, so you may try with

```
@kraken = KrakenClient.load

def withdraw_order_kraken
  params = {
    asset:'xbt',
    key:'Bitstamp',
    amount: 0.005
  }
  @kraken.private.withdraw(params)
end
```